# как в webpack считывать все import'ы?

Tags: javascript, webpack

вот мой app.js:

```
import './scss/style.scss';
import './js/script-1.js';
import './js/script-2.js';
import './css/style-1.css';
import './css/style-2.css';
```

вот часть кода из конфига:

```
    {
      test: /\.js$/g,
      exclude: [/node_modules/],
      use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: { presets: ['es2015'] }
      }]
    },{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "style-loader"
        }, {
            loader: "css-loader"
        }, {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
                includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/compass-mixins/lib")]
            }
        }]
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "style-loader"
        }, {
            loader: "css-loader"
        }]
    }
```

в итоге у меня подключается только один файл стилей или только один скрипт. Пробовал изменить регулярку на `/\.css/g`, тогда вообще ничего не заработало. Может можно как-то более правильно сделать? Это важные самописные библиотеки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваши конфиги(те, что вы дали) абсолютно верны.

Давайте разберемся с Вашими скриптами, а именно формулировкой `jquery` не работает из комментариев. Видно, наличие скриптов в бандле Вы определяли их работоспособностью.
Типичный код webpack точки входа:

```
import "./1.js";
import "./2.js";
```

На выходе Вам даст что-то вроде:

```
(function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
   // 1.js

}),
(function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
   // 2.js
})
```

В этом Вы можете убедится сами, открыв бандл.
Очевидно, что переменная `JQuery` так или иначе объявленная внутри `1.js` останется видна только там. То есть, в `2.js` она уже будет недоступна, с чем Вы и столкнулись.

Почему так сделано за рамками этого вопроса, поэтому попробую дать ответ на вопрос "а что же делать теперь, если я хочу `jquery` и что-то еще в global scope"

В случае с общедоступными библиотеками, вроде той же самой `jquery` удобно использовать

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      JQuery: 'jquery'// $: "jquery", refer to docs
})
```

Для такого использования `jquery` должна быть предварительно установлена как `npm` пакет.

Для самописных проектов - можно оформить их как `npm` пакет.
Пример простого оформления(надеюсь, никого не смутит, что моего авторства): https://github.com/vpotseluyko/url-get-parser

Или же воспользоваться `expose-loader`

Пример:

**Точка входа:**

```
require("expose-loader?varname!./main.js");
```

**Main.js**

```
module.exports = 'my imp string for global scope';
```

Где-то в inline script:

```
console.log(varname); // `my imp string...'(only after webpack script loaded)
```

Comment: сейчас подробно распишу. Может упустил чего

Comment: один из скриптов это jquery. Получается, что подключая `import './js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js';
import './js/script-2.js';` у меня в консоли выводится ошибка, что Jquery не существует. Если я его подключаю отдельной строкой в html, то все работает

Comment: такая же история со стилями. У меня работают стили либо из `import './scss/style.scss';`, либо `import './css/style-1.css';`

Comment: все начинает исправно работать только когда подключаю максимум один файл одного типа. То есть я пробовал их все в один собирать и импортить. Так работает. Жаль, что флаги не работают...

Comment: @Nikolay, Вы запутались с областями видимости webpack. Я отредактирую ответ и отпишусь еще раз в комментариях. Если кратко - у каждого подключенного файла webpack(js) локальная область видимости. Для подключения чего-то, что требует глобальную область надо использовать например webpack.providePlugin.

Comment: @Nikolay отредактировал ответ. Ознакомьтесь:)

Comment: огромное спасибо) теперь стало понятней. Пошел дальше разбираться с webpack

Answer (score -1):

спас [скринкаст](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYP0e7uwgG0&index=10&list=PLDyvV36pndZHfBThhg4Z0822EEG9VGenn) . Нужно просто сделать несколько точек входа

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/179997)

Comment: @terron, так он указал: "сделать несколько точек входа".

Comment: А скринкаст довольно старый, я бы на него не очень полагался. Webpack с тех пор обновился и многое поменялось.

Comment: @Qwertiy, если почитать то, что мне ответили в комментариях, то товарищ запутался не с тем, о чем спрашивает:) и как ему собственно скринкаст и несколько точек входа помогли непонятно